# Environment behaves different inside \cslet{}

Tags: macros, environments, etoolbox

---

Please scroll down for the EDIT and most recent version

---

This is not a good title, but I didn't come up with a better one.

I've got an environment which should be used like this (The way this looks is a MUST be):

```
\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
\setAuthor{Author1}
Content A1
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{A}{2}
\setAuthor{Author2}
Conten A2
\end{Lied}
\begin{Lied}{B}{1}
\setAuthor{Author3}
Content B1
\end{Lied}
```

I want to call the content of the environments via command, so that they are put into the text. Thing like author, source and composer are stored. These things should be placed style-dependent around the content. Therefore, I can call the content of the environments with a command and how they look is dependent from a defined style.

The content should be called by `\csuse{lied;A;1}` for example. It should insert the Author and then the content of Lied-A-1.

Therefore I can call the content of a predefined database with a command.

Here is a example which works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{{
%to save a string
\def\Author{leer}
%to change the string
\def\setAuthor##1{##1}
\long\def\temp{} 
\long\def\test{{\Author \temp}} 
\let\temp\BODY 
%"write" the content of setAuthor to Author
\let\Author\setAuthor
%make output
\test
}}

\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
\setAuthor{Maestro}
Hallo

Absatz1
\end{Lied}

\csuse{lied;A;1}

Absatz2\\
Zeile

Absatz3

\end{document}
```

it gives the following output:

[image: Output.pdf]

If I use `\cslet` like this, it gives an error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{{
\def\Author{leer}
\def\setAuthor##1{##1}
\long\def\temp{} 
\long\def\test{{\Author \temp}} 
\let\temp\BODY 
\let\Author\setAuthor
\global\cslet{lied;#1;#2}\test
}}

\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
\setAuthor{Maestro}
Hallo

Absatz1
\end{Lied}

\csuse{lied;A;1}

Absatz2\\
Zeile

Absatz3

\end{document}
```

If I use only

```
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{\global\cslet{lied;#1;#2}\BODY}
```

it works fine, but without the `\Author`-part

---

EDIT:

The following code has been simplified to show the purpose more clearly. In general, it should be used in a package, which should be published later. If it works, there can be generated songbooks in very simple way. From these songbooks there can be inserted songs in existing documents via a simple command. Styles shall describe how they appear, when imported.

---

The following code works and works 100% exactly like it should do, except for the fact, that it breaks, if I use a `\\` inside the environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%%%The following code defines my default style. Right now, it only contains only the author
\def\stylehead{\Author}
\def\stylefoot{}

%%%This would redefine the commands stylehead and stylefoot. Casual would be some external .sty-file
%\usestyle{casual}

%This code maybe changed.
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{{
\def\Author{leer}
\def\setAuthor##1{##1}
\long\def\temp{} 
\long\def\test{{\stylehead \BODY \stylefoot}}
\let\Author\setAuthor %This applies setAuthor (defined in \BODY) to Author (used in \stylehead)
\global\csedef{lied;#1;#2}{\test}
}}

%%%This code may not be changed. That is a contraint of the project
\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
\setAuthor{Maestro}
%uncommenting the next line breaks the code
Hallo%\\ this is in a new line

Absatz1
\end{Lied}

%%%document for testing
\begin{document}

\csuse{lied;A;1}

Absatz2\\
Zeile

Absatz3

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use `\Collect@Body` directly and giving it a macro that stores the body contents in a macro immediately. The that is what I always do, then I do not have to fiddle around with stuff like this.

Comment: And why not just have setAuthor globally define Author, again I do not really see the need for those let constructions

Comment: @daleif The reason is simple: Their will be dozens of Lieder in a row, which should be called with a command (therefore the lets). author should be defined inside the \BODY. I didnt know Collect@ yet.

Comment: It would probably be good if you gave a simple description of the desired behaviour, it is very hard to guess that from the code.

Comment: You still need to rethink this. Might be easier to wrap the part inside the lied in an extra env (for structure), then use environ to extract just that part, now you have author and the rest stored in two separate macros. If you're clever you can make it retrievable via `\csuse{lied-A-1-autjor}` plus a similar one for the other part. This way you get around the expansion problem David has already talked about. The Lied env can even just be an empty construction.

Comment: @daleif The problem is, that it won't be restricted to author. There might be a lot of other fields like source, composer,...

Comment: Can you explain what's the purpose of `\setAuthor` and of `\let\Author\setAuthor`? I see no use of them: as defined, `\setAuthor` just outputs its argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope it is a bit more clearly now.

Comment: @egreg Author can be left out and fully replaced by `\setAuthor`. You are right. This is a bit confusing.

Comment: The ud you just add more storage macros that just store the data. I do not see the problem

Comment: You might what to explain exactly what you want, it is not clear from your code or comments

Comment: Will `\setAuthor` always be the *first* token in the environment if used? (And do you plan to extend this? `\setArranger`…?)

Comment: No it is not clear at all,  you haven't said what the intended output of your code is, you define author by \def\Author{leer} but never use that value, then you redefine author to \let\Author\setAuthor where \setauthor is a command that does nothing but echo its argument what do you want this code to do???????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @clemens No, there might be others also and it might also be empty.

Comment: The emptiness isn't a problem but further such commands will make it extremely difficult if not impossible to solve in a general way.

Comment: it's slightly clearer but the comment  here still does not match the code `\let\Author\setAuthor %This applies setAuthor (defined in \BODY) to Author (used in \stylehead)` the let does not apply anything, it just defined `\Author` to be like `\setAuthor` which does nothing useful, `\setAuthor{foo}` is just the same as `foo`

Comment: `\\ ` would be safe if you used `\unexpanded` as in my answer, which was why I added it, to prevent `\BODY` expanding more than once.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried several versions with \expandafter\unexpanded, but they failed. Either no output or an error.  The problem is, as far as I can see: no matter, what kind of `\expandafter` or `\unexpanded` is used, the moment `\setAuthor` in `\BODY` is evaluated, `\\\` is evaluated also.

Comment: `\setAuthor` _does absolutely nothing_ why do you have the command at all?

Comment: I have added an annotated version of your code as I can say what it does but I still can't guess what you want it to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. It seemed to work, but it didn't, it did by coincidence. Still working on this one. I suppose, I have to stick to an extra parameter like someone here suggested. - Right now I follow the strategy: Make it work, then find out why. I will try some variations with \Collect@Body and see if I get anywhere. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't break lines with `\\ ` anyway except in special contexts such as `tabular` or `array`.

Comment: @cfr I know, but I have such context. i.e. in a poem their must be linebreaks where there are linebreaks and not pars.

Comment: But then you should use a suitable environment for that content and not just insert the line breaks with `\\ `.

Comment: Maybe, but it won't solve the basic problem. We should leave this question so far. If I come up with a solution, I will post it. But thanks to all for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
\global\cslet{lied;#1;#2}\test
\show\test
```

you will see that `\test` and so `lied;..;..` is defined as

```
> \test=\long macro:
->{\Author \temp }.
```

but `\Author` and `\temp` are only locally defined so not defined outside the group, where you try to use this.

I couldn't work out the intended behaviour, but this is error free.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{{%
\def\Author{leer}%%%
\def\setAuthor##1{##1}%%%
\let\Author\setAuthor
\csxdef{lied;#1;#2}%
{{%
\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\Author{??}} % space intended here?
\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}%%%
}}

\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
Hallo

Absatz1
\end{Lied}

\csuse{lied;A;1}

Absatz2\\
Zeile

Absatz3

\end{document}
```

---

**annotated version of the original**

```
\def\stylehead{\Author}
```

This defines `\stylehead` to `\Author` which is either (depending when you do the evaluation) the fixed string `leer` or a macro with definition `\def\Author#1{#1}` in which case it will grab and copy the next token after `\stylehead` (which is `\BODY` in the example here).

```
\def\stylefoot{}
```

this defined `\stylefoot` to be empty

```
%%%This would redefine the commands stylehead and stylefoot. Casual would be some external .sty-file
%\usestyle{casual}
```

OK

```
%This code maybe changed.
\NewEnviron{Lied}[2]{{
```

this starts an additional group, in addition to the group for the environment
and adds a space token due to the missing `%` before the end of line.

```
\def\Author{leer}
```

this defines `\Author` to be `leer` and then inserts a space token

```
\def\setAuthor##1{##1}
```

this (which could be outside the definition) defines `\SetAuthor` to be the same as `\@firstofone` so `\SetAuthor{anything}` expands to `anything` so the command never does anything very useful. Then a space  token is inserted.

```
\long\def\temp{}
```

defines `\temp` to be empty (`\long` not doing much) Then a space token is inserted.

```
\long\def\test{{\stylehead \BODY \stylefoot}}
```

defines `\temp` to be `\stylehead \BODY \stylefoot` inside a group.  (`\long` not doing much). then a space token is inserted.

```
\let\Author\setAuthor %This applies setAuthor (defined in \BODY) to Author (used in \stylehead)
```

The comment appears to be false, this just makes `\Author` have the same definition as `\SetAuthor` so it is like `\newcommand\Author[1]{#1}`

```
\global\csedef{lied;#1;#2}{\test}
```

this globally defines \lied'..;.. but applying edef to arbitrary latex tokens is not supported, you will break most commands (`\\` being just one example)
again a space token is inserted due to missing `%`.

You need to control expansion either using `\unexpanded` primitive or `\expandonce` from etoolbox or
 `\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname lied;#1;#2\endcsname{\test}%`

```
}}
```

this ends the inner group and the definition.

```
\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
\setAuthor{Maestro}
```

this is the same as

```
\begin{Lied}{A}{1}
Maestro
```

as `\SetAuthor` just copies its argument.

Comment: If I use csedef instead of cslet, it seems to work. But if the environment contains a `\\` it breaks again.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I was just making an example I've updated the answer but I couldn't really guess what the code was trying to do, why define `\SetAuthor`  every time (to a macro that does nothing)  and why the local unused `\temp` etc?

Comment: The point is, that Author shall be defined from within \BODY. In your example, you simply deleted the line (after `\begin{Lied}{A}{1}`). That's the whole point.

Comment: You have two redundant `\expandafter`'s

Comment: @MaestroGlanz you have given no hint what the code is supposed to do, just posted non working code. I can make it error free but I can't look inside your head to know what you want it to do.

Comment: @egreg the more the merrier.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make this work; the settings such as `\setAuthor` must be evaluated before `\BODY` is expanded for being stored in the `lied` macro. You can add a third argument where making the settings. But you're probably using a wrong approach: a key-value one would be better.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\setAuthor}[1]{\def\Author{#1}}
\setAuthor{leer} % default

\NewEnviron{Lied}[3]{%
  \par#3
  \csxdef{lied;#1;#2}{\expandonce{\Author} \expandonce{\BODY}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Lied}{A}{1}{
  \setAuthor{Maestro}
}
Hallo

Absatz1
\end{Lied}

\csuse{lied;A;1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that a syntax such as

```
\begin{Lied}{
  class=A,
  number=1,
  author=Author,
  title=Title,
  publisher=Publisher,
}
Text of the lied\\
with line breaks
\end{Lied}
```

would be much easier to manage.

Comment: I'm aware of the points you mentioned. So, I was thinking, if it is possible, to evaluate the content of \BODY, store it somewhere and use it later. If I use `\csedef` instead of `\cslet`, it works almost. It breaks it I use `\\` in the `\BODY`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz No, an `\edef` will perform no assignment. On the other hand, it's difficult reading your mind, so you should explain more clearly what's your aim.

Comment: I changed the first third of the question. I hope, this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: It is a "chicken or the egg" problem. How can I access some content of `\BODY` and insert the rest into the document after that.

Comment: I considered the suggested version with class=..... already. But it isn't what I wish.